# Problem 1.24, Introduction to representation theory, Etingof

Tags: representation-theory

Let $k$ be a field and $n$ and $N$ be two nonnegative integers. Let $A = k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, and let $I \neq A$ be any ideal in $A$ containing all homogeneous polynomials of degree $\geq N$. Show that $A/I$ is an indecomposable representation of $A$.

Comment: We generally prefer that you at least share us your thoughts on the problem... Have you tried some small case, like the one you get when $N=1$ or $N=2$?

Comment: Well, $N = 1$ is trivial; in this case the representation is just the field $k$. Thinking about $N = 2$...

Comment: I can come up with a proof for $N = 2$ but it doesn't seem to be useful as I can't easily generalize it to $N > 2$. If $A_1 \oplus A_2 = A/I$, then either $A_1$ or $A_2$ must contain an element with a nonzero constant term. We assume it is not a constant otherwise this subrepresentation must obviously be the entirety of $A/I$. By multiplying this by each $x_i$ in turn we see that this subspace contains all $x_i$. Then the other subspace must be simply $k$, but then it cannot be invariant.

Comment: Well, then concentrate on the case $N=3$ which is at the frontiers of your knowledge!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I might have solved this finally. I think this may be a possible solution, but twice before this I thought I had a solution that subsequently turned out to be completely bogus.

If $A/I = A_1 \oplus A_2$, then either $A_1$ or $A_2$ must contain an element with a nonzero constant term. Without loss of generality, take this to be $A_1$, and let this element be $a$.  Furthermore, without loss of generality, take the constant term to be 1.

By multiplying each homogeneous polynomial of degree $N-1$ by $a$ (which kills off all the non-constant terms), we see that $A_1$, an invariant subspace, must in fact contain all homogeneous polynomials of degree $N-1$.

Then we successively multiply each homogeneous polynomial of degree $N-k$ by $a$, for $k = 2, 3, \ldots$. This kills off all the terms of degree at least $k$, and all the terms of degree $1, 2, \ldots k-1$ go to homogeneous polynomials of degree $N-k+1, \ldots, N-1$ which are in $A_1$, so we may subtract them off. This leave the contribution from the constant term, the original homogeneous polynomial. So we can successively show that all homogeneous polynomials of degree $N-k$ are in $A_1$, and conclude that $A_1 = A/I$.

Therefore $A/I$ is indecomposable.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you had the right idea but I didn't get all the details of what you wrote. (especially, is a a polynomial of degree 1?)

That essential idea is that $A/I$ has a unit, which is a cyclic vector. Then, in full generality, a representation with a cyclic vector is indecomposable.

(I also discovered that great lesson by etingof and I'm try to do the exercices!!)

Comment: The representation $A \oplus A$ of $A$ has cyclic vector $(1,1)$ but is decomposable...

Comment: I mean the regular representation of $A\oplus A$

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your comments. First anwser: a cyclic vector is supposed to generate the whole representation so where is your direct sum of two non trivial subrepresentations (def. of decomposable)? Second: what is your reg. representation of $A\oplus A$? $A\oplus A$ (as a sum of two modules) is supposed to mean all couples $(a_1,a_2)$ and in that case $(1,1)$ is not cyclic. I guess that now you have to take away the downvote, mouahahaha

Comment: My first comment contains a typo which is clarified in my second comment. Regular representation means $A\oplus A$ acts on itself by multiplication. $(1,1)$ is a cyclic vector obviously. Subrepresentations include $A\oplus 0$ and $0\oplus A$. As for the downvote, you'll need to ask whoever did it.

Comment: It seems that you're right finally... I'll modify my answer later, i was actually thinking about something more than cyclicity, like a single element of the algebra acting repeatedly on the cyclic vector and generating the whole representation

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A/I=U\oplus V$ and write $\overline{1}=\overline{u}+\overline{w}$ with $\overline{u}\in U$, $\overline{v}\in V$. It is easy to see that $\overline u,\overline v$ are orthogonal idempotents. If we suppose $\overline{u}$ and $\overline{v}$ are non-zero, it follows that both $u$ and $v$ have non-zero constant term, since otherwise $\overline{u}^N=\overline{v}^N=0$, contradicting their idempotence.

Let $\lambda\in k^\times$ be such that $u+\lambda v$ has zero constant term. Then $$0=(\overline{u}+\lambda\overline{v})^N=\sum_{j=0}^N \binom{N}{j} \overline{u}^j(\lambda\overline{v})^{N-j}=\overline{u}^N+(\lambda\overline{v})^{N}=\overline{u}+\lambda^N\overline{v},$$

which is obviously contradictory.